# figures: return the figure number rather than the section number when there is no caption

Tags: floats, captions, labels

I want to be able to number my figures using the figure counter, not the section number, but am unable to do this without including a caption.      Of course a potential (hideous) kludge  would be to include a `\caption{}` before the `\label` but by default, this would result in `FIGURE 1:`  when I really don't want a caption at all.    So, if it's really impossible (extremely hard to believe) that you *have* to have a caption in order to have  a figure number, then how can I tamper with `\caption` so that it doesn't return anything, even white space?

The code below illustrates the problem: `\ref{myLabel}` will return `In figure 1.1.1`.
Here is the bunny:
[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{bunny.jpg}
\label{myLabel}
\end{figure}
In figure \ref{myLabel},

\end{document}
```

~

Comment: Would it be for all figures?

Comment: Cue mightily confused readers, when they come across to a cross-reference to a figure that, by construction, is not numbered. What do expect readers will think if they come across a cross-reference to a Figure 5 but there's is no figure numbered 5 anywhere in the document?

Comment: You can also use `\expandafter\edef\csname @currentlabel\endcsname{\thesection}`. See also \phantomsection

Comment: Thanks for your comments, guys.    The problem I have is that many of my figures already have a title, so I don't want to duplicate it.    But responding to  @Mico's point (which is obvious ex post!) I guess the best thing to do is to just have a blank caption, returning FIGURE 1: and nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

There is no counter increment associated with the `figure` environment, only with `\caption` however you can use `\refstepcounter{figure}` before the `\label` if you want the counter to increment unseen.

Answer (score 1):

(this answer incorporates information provided by the OP in a comment below the main query)

If you use `\caption{}` to create captions without caption text, the colon that's inserted by LaTeX after `Figure 1`, `Figure 2`, etc probably doesn't look quite right, since there's no text to which the caption header cum colon points to.

If you share this view, you may want to load the [caption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package. That way, the trailing colon after `Figure x` and `Table y` will be omitted automatically if the argument of `\caption` is either empty or consists of whitespace only.

To verify this statement, simply compile the following sample code -- note the absence of a colon in the `\caption{}` and `\caption{   }` cases.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!] 
  \caption{Hello} 
\end{table}
\begin{figure}[h!] 
  \caption{} 
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[h!] 
  \caption{   } 
\end{table}
\begin{figure}[h!] 
  \caption{World} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```